# How to find this Remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Don't use modular arithmetic, and show that:

For a integer m. If dividing $m$ by $18$ yields remainder $r$, then what's the remainder when dividing $-2m$ by $6$?

What I tried:

We can write $m = 18q + r$ for some integers q, r.

So, $-2m = 6(-6q) - 2r$

So, it should represent the euclidean division of -2m for 6 and yelding a $reminder = -2r$

But, it doesn't seems to work the way I want, for example:

$m = 99$, so $99 = 5 * 18 + 9$

$r=9$

$-2m = -198$, so $-198 = 6 * (-33)$

$r=0$

So, am I ignoring something? And how can I get a more accurately answer that bypass this?

Comment: You are ignoring the fact that $-2r$ could be smaller than $0$ , so it wouldn't count as a remainder because the remainder needs to be between $0$ and $6$. More concretely, the answer to your question is the remainder of $-2r$ upon division by $6$.

Comment: I don't see any tangible difference between the Euclidean Algorithm and *modular arithmetic*.  If the [no modular arithmetic] constraint came from you, you might wish to reconsider it.  If instead, the constraint came from someone else (e.g. a teacher), this is bizarre; perhaps the teacher is under some sort of stress.  $a\equiv b\pmod{c} \iff c ~|~ (a-b).$  So modular arithmetic is embedded in the Euclidean Algorithm.  That is, $a = Pb + r \implies b ~|~ (a-r) \implies a \equiv r \pmod{b}.$